# JButton not appearing on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jbutton

Following is the code in which the jbutton is not showing on the frame. I have also set visible to true. Even then the button doesn't appear.

```
class gui{
        public static void main(String args[]){
            layoutBorder lb=new layoutBorder("check");
        }
    }

class layoutBorder extends JFrame{
    layoutBorder(String title){
        super(title);
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(200, 200);
        JButton jb=new JButton("JB");
        add(jb);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want `null` layouts then you need to set sizes and position by yourself. Using the `setLocation` and `setSize` methods.

```
class gui{
        public static void main(String args[]){
            layoutBorder lb=new layoutBorder("check");
        }
    }

class layoutBorder extends JFrame{
    layoutBorder(String title){
        super(title);
        setLayout(null);
        setSize(200, 200);
        JButton jb=new JButton("JB");
        jb.setLocation(10, 10);
        jb.setSize(40, 30);
        add(jb);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a solution! Using random numbers to set the size of a  Swing component is not the way was designed to be used. As a beginner, learn to use Swing properly!

Comment: (1-) It doesn't matter if it works. That is NOT the way Swing was designed to be used for so many reasons. For example look at the "At Comment" button right on this forum. Notice how the button is sized to fit the text with an appropriate border. The size will change as the text changes. What do the numbers 40 and 30 mean in your code. They are just random numbers that mean nothing. If the text changes then what happens. Layout managers allow you to create dynamic GUIs that are easy to change. The code only works in a very limited sense.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a null layout!!!

Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial o [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information.

I suggest you download the working examples and play with them. The example will also show you how to better structure your code. Maybe start with the code from `How to Use Buttons`, which has a simple example that adds 3 buttons to a panel and then the panel to the frame.

Also, class names should start with an upper case character. Have you even seen a class in the API that doesn't??? Learn Java conventions and follow them.

Comment: As I am new to Java programming that's why I have missed the conventions. I'll be keeping Java conventions in mind from now on.

Comment: `As I am new to Java programming` - why did you un-accept my answer? The answer I gave you is the proper solution. You should NOT be using a null layout.  You should NOT be guessing what the size of a component should be The tutorial link I gave you explains why you should be using layout manager. But there is also a section on `Doing Without a Layout Manager` that you can read. Also, as a new person to programming the tutorial provides your with a resource for other basic Swing information for the next time you have a problem.

Comment: I would suspect the answer was unaccepted because someone else gave what appears to be working copy/paste-able code. Shame really.

Comment: The layout thing seems difficult to me. Initially, my Instructor started teaching with this 'null' layout concept. That is why I am avoiding it.'

Comment: @OmarMalik, `Initially, my Instructor started teaching with this 'null' layout concept` - and that is the problem. You learn bad habits instead of learning how to create dynamic flexible GUIs.

Comment: I followed what you said. I have implemented grid layout in my code. But  now the components are not shown on the jframe. When I maximize it, the components are too big in size. How do I control their size?

Comment: @OmarMalik, You use a different layout manager. I already gave you a link to the tutorial. Start with the FlowLayout. That is the simplest. Or I suggest the `How to Use Buttons` section from the tutorial is the best place to start. The code from that example is better structured and a better example for your to follow.

Answer (score 0):

camickr is right. Also, always use the AWT event dispatching thread when an application thread needs to update the GUI.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Gui {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            MyFrame frame = new MyFrame("check");
        });
    }
}

class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    MyFrame(String title){
        super(title);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setSize(200, 200);
        JButton jb = new JButton("JB");
        add(jb);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```